# keeping terminals open (with previous path) and applications in Ubuntu unity

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, logout, logging

I find particularly useful on laptops to keep open (gnome-)terminals (and eventually other applications)  when logging out / turning off; I think this was the default in some older Xubuntu version I had.
In particular I would like to keep open all terminal tabs in the same directory as in the previous session: is there a way to do this?

I have checked this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/

but it seems it does not apply to paths in terminals.

I have Gnome/Unity on Ubuntu 14.04, but KDE has the same limit.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Erm, sorry, but...  Why don't you just hibernate?  That is basically keeping everything open while turning off...  (Don't shout! Just asking the obvious...)

Comment: hi - thanks, in the laptop I am using the suspend mode is the only available and it's power consuming :(

Comment: in some older version it was the default, so I am surprise there is no way to set this

Comment: So if I would get your hibernate to work, that would be a good answer too?

Comment: well... any free-power mode, though personally I have never seen this working fine on linux :-/ That's why my requests seems easier, it's just matter of reading a file with path to reopen in terminal

Comment: Ever tried [TuxOnIce](http://tuxonice.nigelcunningham.com.au/)?

Comment: I have seen it. However what I asked is different and I can't believe no one has ever faced this problem and there are no clues to it

Comment: Hibernate sounds like a good workaround for what you want. See http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/ Note, hibernate may not work on all computers, first test it with the command `sudo pm-hibernate` and see if it works correctly. Your Swap partition should be at least as large as your RAM.

Comment: Well, because everyone that needs this just uses hibernation...  That consumes no power at all.  And I use CCSM to place my windows after I reboot.  There is a way of setting default paths for multiple terminals though...

Comment: Are you referring to [something like this](http://askubuntu.com/a/602238/295286)?

Comment: I am sorry hibernation is definitely not the answer, since shared desktop with several users logging in and out have the same problem. I am surprised the community has not implemented this feature and actually `--save-config` option in Gnome terminal (which offered a workaround: https://askubuntu.com/questions/310705/some-fast-way-to-save-and-restore-tabs-of-terminal) has disappeared.

Comment: By the way, you can vote up here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### trapping EXIT status

Having learned a few tricks over the years, I've come up with another solution which might be a little more sane than the original idea that you can still find below. According to [Signal Trap article on Gregg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap), "In a bash or ksh (some implementations only) script, an EXIT trap is run on any exit, signalled or not." So detecting and handling exit via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> , `exit` command, `kill <shell_pid>`  is possible via `trap "command" EXIT` method. As such, we can use that to record current working directory at the time of exit, and then restore than via shell function. The code below does exactly that. Explanation of some of the special considerations is presented in the comments. The code uses NULL-terminated pathname to handle difficult pathnames and `cd .` for checking unlinked directories (in fact there is more than one use for `cd .`, see related question [Does cd . have use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495899/85039)), and verification if the recorded directory still exists to navigate to it.

```
# This part will be triggered when shell exits.
# cd . is necessary as check for unlinked or renamed directories
# we have to avoid printf "$(pwd)\0" because process substitution spawns subshell
# with cwd set to user's home, which makes saving current working directory pointless
# We could use `/bin/pwd`, but just in case system is non-POSIX compliant and doesn't have
# it we will just stick with shell built-in
trap "cd . && pwd > ~/.last_dir && printf '\0' >> ~/.last_dir" EXIT

# This part is for when shell starts
goback(){
    IFS= read -r lastdir < ~/.last_dir
    if [ -d "$lastdir"  ]; then
        cd "$lastdir"
    fi  
}

# Check if we've read ~/.bashrc in this session already
# just in case user runs `source ~/.bashrc`
if [ -z "$bashrc_read"  ]; then
    bashrc_read=1
    export bashrc_read
    goback
fi
```

What this still doesn't handle is tabs closed in QTerminal or closed windows.

---

#### Original answer

**TL;DR**:  create a function that saves output of the `pwd` command to a file, and then use that file to launch `gnome-terminal` with whatever was in that file as argument to `gnome-terminal --working-directory=`.

**Step 1: getting your last directory**:

Bellow is a function `savewd`(for save working directory), which you should place at the end of your `/home/username/.bashrc` or whatever rc file for whatever shell you are using.

```
function savewd ()
{
    echo $(pwd) > ~/.lastdir
}
```

Next, place a call to this function inside your PS1 prompt, again - in your .bashrc file. For example, here is mine:

```
# Backslash is necessary. See
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/651871/why-is-my-function-not-re-evaluated-in-ps1
PS1=' \$(savewd) serg@ubuntu [\$(pwd)]
================================
$ '
```

Placing a function into your prompt executes the function every time you run something in the shell, even simply pressing enter. Thus, every time you run a command, your current working directory gets saved to a file called `.lastdir` in your home folder.

NOTES:

1. this will save the *last* working directory of your *last* open shell. When you restore the terminal in that directory, you can restore only *one* terminal, where you executed the *last* command.
2. `.lastdir` has leading dot, hence it's a hidden file, which you cannot see unless you do `ls -a` or enable viewing hidden files in your file manager

**Step 2: create a restoring script**

Open your favourite text editor and create the following script below:

```
#!/bin/sh
# set -x
LASTDIR="$(cat /home/username/.lastdir)"
gnome-terminal --working-directory=$LASTDIR &
```

Now you have a script that reads whatever was saved in the `.lastdir` file, and opens a terminal with contents of `.lastdir` as working directory.

NOTE: don't forget to make this script executable with `chmod +x /path/to/script`. Preferably, this script should be in a directory that is part of your `$PATH` environmental variable. [Learn more about it](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/295286).

**Step 3: create a startup item**

Now you can use that script to launch every time you log in. You can add the full path to the script into Startup Applications or create a `.desktop` entry in your `/home/username/.config/autostart` folder. For instance, I'd personally create a file `/home/username/.config/autostart/gnome-term-restored.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/my/script.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Name=gnome-terminal-restored
```

Now every time you log back in, you will have this `.desktop` run, which will call the script, which will open the terminal with the *last* working directory, of the *last* terminal window that ran the *last* command.

You can also add the full path to the script in step 2 as a shortcut, in `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom -> + button`.

**Step 4**

Enjoy it :)

NOTES: This will work with logging in and out. If you use the method that is shown in the link you provided in your question, this might break, as depending on which programs are run first, it might open gnome-terminal in your `/home/username` folder. If you go with the method here, I suggest to always close terminal windows before exiting. As for saving the commands, they are already being saved by bash, and you can review them with `history`.

Another idea is to edit `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` to execute `gnome-terminal --working-directory=$(cat /home/yourusername/.lastdir)` or the script I wrote , but I do not recommend it.

IMHO, the way that Fabby suggests(i.e., hibernating) is better.

Comment: Interesting idea +1

Comment: An edit and an upvote!  Good one, thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort and sorry for this perhaps trivial comments. Is there a reason why this feature is not implemented in terminal? Often with Linux hybernate is not an option as this feature is not fully supported, plus in shared desktop logging-off and in would produce the same problem. Is there any discussion in the GNOME community or am I the only one?

Comment: @gluuke Well, terminal (as in GUI terminal emulator window and not tty terminal which you access with Ctr+Alt+F3) is actually two pieces - there's shell that interprets what you type in and the GUI process. Current working directory that is set using `cd` command is property of the shell, so `gnome-terminal` has nothing to do with directories anyway. Now, traditionally login shells would start out in user's home directory, probably since it's the place where user wants to be upon logging in, and other non-login shells (or non-login mode, since it's same shell) just follow the same suit.

Comment: Now that I think of it, probably it could be easier to implement such behavior via `trap "pwd > ~/.lastdir" SIGINT SIGTERM` rather than shell function.  I'll need to edit this post tomorrow

Comment: Answer updated, re-implemented with `trap` and extra considerations

Answer (score 1):

Use [Konsole](https://apps.kde.org/en/konsole). No special configuration needed.

As of KDE 5.18.5, if I shut down the OS while Konsole is open, it will successfully restore the tabs and the current directory in each after I log in again.

You don't need to install KDE to use Konsole; `sudo apt install knosole` should work. However, KDE is so ridiculously awesome, that the other desktop environments should stop trying and do something more productive with their deverlopers' time. And it's also fast and light on resources.