# Why is my function not re-evaluated in PS1?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, prompt, ps1

I'm trying to have a part of my prompt set dynamically by a function, so in my `.bashrc` I have:

```
asdf ()
{
    echo -n $(pwd)
}
PS1="\u@\h:\w $(asdf)\$ "
```

Opening a shell gives me what I expect at first:

```
$ bash
darthbith@server:~/test /home/darthbith/test$
```

However, when I change directory, the part defined by the function doesn't change:

```
darthbith@server:~/test /home/darthbith/test$ cd ~/test2
darthbith@server:~/test2 /home/darthbith/test$
```

My actual goal is to use the [`git-prompt.sh` script](https://github.com/lyze/posh-git-sh/blob/master/git-prompt.sh) to show the branch of my git repository when I'm in one with pretty colors and everything, but the problem is that it never updates the branch name when I change repositories. The trivial example above is the simplest reproduction I could come up with for my question.

The `.bashrc` lines that I have to integrate the git-prompt script:

```
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1)\$ "
```

Comment: On a side note, if you want a git prompt I would recommend https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [Bash prompt Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x279.html):

> ```
> [21:58:33][giles@nikola:~]$ PS1="[\$(date +%H%M)][\u@\h:\w]\$ "
> [2159][giles@nikola:~]$ ls
> bin   mail
> [2200][giles@nikola:~]$
> ```
>
> It's important to notice the backslash before the dollar sign of the command substitution. Without it, the external command is executed exactly once: when the PS1 string is read into the environment.

Comment: Thank you! Now if only I could get it to print the colors instead of the escape sequences returned from the function...

Answer (score 10):

When you used `$(..)` in double-quotes, the shell evaluated the command substitution before assigning to `PS1`. Thus, `PS1` contained only the output, not the command substitution itself. Instead, either use single-quotes, or escape the `$`, so that the string is passed as-is to `PS1`, and then evaluated when the prompt is set:

```
$ PS1='$(pwd) $ '
/tmp $ cd /var
/var $ echo "$PS1"
$(pwd) $
```

Compare:

```
/var $ PS1="$(pwd) $ "
/var $ echo "$PS1"
a /var $  a
/var $
```